# how to Reset AutoIncrement in SQL Server after all data Deleted

Tags: sql-server-2005, auto-increment

i got a function in sql that generate sequential series of alphanumeric
no.like (c000,c0001 .......)  , which is working good . but when i deleted all data in table , it  starts from last generated no. i want it to reset its value from  "c0000" .

code is as follows :-

```
create table Customers
(
dbID int identity not null primary key,
CustomerName varchar(100)
)

 create function CustomerNumber (@id int) 
  returns char(5) 
  as 
 begin 
 return 'C' + right('0000' + convert(varchar(10), @id), 4) 
  end

  alter table Customers add CustomerNumber as dbo.CustomerNumber(dbID)
```

thanks in advance....

EDIT 1 -

how to update it to increment based on last value . means if last entry having no. c0053 , and i deleted this record , so when next entry added it should have value "C0053" not "C0054".

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TRUNCATE TABLE**

Removes all rows from a table or specified partitions of a table, without logging the individual row deletions. TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to the DELETE statement with no WHERE clause; however, TRUNCATE TABLE is faster and uses fewer system and transaction log resources.

TRUNCATE TABLE Customers

or remove your in build function.

Comment: Of course, this **only** works if no other table is referencing the `Customers` table via a foreign key - rather unlikely in any decently designed DB design ....

Answer (score 6):

Truncate Table Command is good way to reset Identity, but there is other command also to reset Identity after deletion of records.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (TableName, RESEED, 0)
```

After Deleting you can use this command to reset Identity to 0.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is instead of **deleting** all rows of data why dont you **truncate** the table.

If you are **truncate** the table it automatically reset your auto increment to 0

```
TRUNCATE TABLE your_table_name;
```

This example would truncate the table and remove all records from that table. and rest your auto increment too.

The SQL **TRUNCATE TABLE** command is used to delete complete data from an existing table

Try this way. May help you.